# Configure VPN via .PBK file

Tags: vpn, ipsec, l2tp

There is some software which can only configure VPN/L2TP-IPSec connection using pbk file (GUI has very limited number of the options).

I'm looking for pbk documentation but unsuccessul. I see a few examples on the web but can't find any detailed (with enumaration and description of all possible keys) manual.
can someone share link/doc for this please?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has some documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rrasm/4c69805f-b6ff-4e4a-9507-e3862f515d2c). See each entry under `2.2.2.2` for details about each key. Note that this list is not complete; for example, `NumRoutes` and `Routes` are not there (see the answers [here](https://serverfault.com/q/1051424/419709)). There's also a [PDF](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-RRASM/%5BMS-RRASM%5D-140515.pdf) of the Microsoft docs which may be easier to search.